# Can't see the mySql syntax error

Tags: mysql, pdo

Sorry for the dumb question, but I'am not able to figure out my typo:

```
INSERT INTO lunchmenu (rid, date, repeat, approved) VALUES ('32', '2011-10-18', '3', '0')
```

I get an mySQL (v5) error saying

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'repeat, approved) VALUES ('32', '2011-10-18', '3', '0')' at line
>   1

My table structure is

```
   Field    Type    Size - NULL - Key - Attribute - Default - Extra
1. id       int     11     no     PI    unsigned              auto_increment
2. rid      int     11     no           unsigned                
3. date     date           no     I                     
4. repeat   tinyint 1      no           unsigned    0           
5. approved int     10     no     I     unsigned    0
```

Any hint for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`date` and `repeat` are [reserved words in mySQL.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Wrap them in backticks, or use different column names.

Comment: Uuuuuuh... I knew it was dumb! Thanks for alle the right answers...!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`REPEAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_repeat) and [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) are a reserved and you need to escape it using backticks ` to use it as a column.

```
INSERT INTO `lunchmenu` (`rid`, `date`, `repeat`, `approved`) VALUES ....
```

It's a good practise to always escape column and table names.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO lunchmenu (rid, `date`, `repeat`, approved) 
VALUES (32, '2011-10-18', 3, 0)
```

`Date` and `repeat` are reserved words, so you have to use backticks for them.
Other reserved words can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: @alinoz: yes, but why using quotes for numeric values?

Comment: no reason, i just wanted to point out that the error is in another place.

Comment: @alinoz: yes, you're right. Anyway my answer would cover that fact also, just to be complete :)

Answer (score 0):

`DATE` and `REPEAT` are reserved keywords in MySQL, try

```
INSERT INTO lunchmenu AS l (l.rid, l.date, l.repeat, l.approved) VALUES ('32', '2011-10-18', '3', '0')
```

This would make your database parse them explicitly as columns.